# let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation defined by $T(X)=A(X)$. Compute $\det(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Question: Let $V$ be a vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field $F$.  Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}\in V$ and let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation defined by $T(X)=A(X)$.  Compute $\det(T)$.

My thoughts: So, $\det(A)=ad-bc$ (not sure if this will help).  Let's take a $2\times 2$ matrix $X=\begin{bmatrix} 
e & f \\
g & h 
\end{bmatrix}$, and compute $AX$.  So, $AX=\begin{bmatrix} 
ae+bg & af+bh \\
ce+dg & cf+dh 
\end{bmatrix}$.  So, since $T(x)=AX$, then wouldn't the determinant of $T(x)$ just be $(cf+dh)(ae+bg)-(ce+dg)(af+bh)$?

Comment: Fix a basis and find the matrix of the transformation

Comment: @User Note that the determinant of $T$ is not the same thing as the determinant of $T(X)$.

Comment: For $n\gt 2$ you may find the Kronecker Product to be interesting.  E.g. it gives the identity $\text{vec}\big(ABC\big) = \big(C^T \otimes A\big)\text{vec}\big( B\big)$, so $T$ is isomorphic to $\big(I\otimes A\big)\text{vec}\big( X\big)$, and Kronecker products have easy to understand properties for e.g. determinants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a matrix $X \in V$, you've computed $T(X)$. Now to represent matrices in $V$ as vectors, you can just reshape the $2 \times 2$ matrices as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then the matrix representation of $T$ is the $4\times 4$ matrix $M$ such that
$$M \begin{bmatrix} e \\ f \\ g \\ h\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ae+bg \\ af+bh \\ ce+dg \\ cf+dh\end{bmatrix}$$
and compute $\det M$.

(Note that different "reshapings" of a $2 \times 2$ matrix into a vector will lead to slightly different matrices $M$, but the determinant will always be the same because the determinant does not change under changes of basis.)

Comment: Ah, okay, so I just need to find a suitable matrix $M$, and then take the determinant of that $4\times 4$ matrix.  When trying to find $M$, is there a "nifty" way of trying to find $M$, or is it best to just play around with things that "feel" are good, and then refine from there?

Comment: @User7238 The entry $ae+bg$ will tell you what the first row of $M$ is; the entry $af+bh$ will tell you the second row, etc.

Comment: So, I get that $M$ is the matrix with $0$ everywhere, but each entry of the diagonal is $\frac{1}{e}(ae+bg)$, $\frac{1}{f}(af+bh)$, $\frac{1}{g}(ce+dg)$, and $\frac{1}{h}(cf+dh)$, respectively.  Then, since $M$ is diagonal, $det(M)$ is just the product of the four entries I have above.... Does that look good?

Comment: @User7238 No, $M$ is $\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 & b \\ c & 0 & d & 0 \\ 0 & c & 0 & d\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  And then we get the determinant is $a^2d^2-2abcd+b^2c^2$

Answer (score 2):

We can start by the case that $A$ is diagonalisable and let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be its eigen values and respectively $x$ and $y$ its eigen vectors. Since $(x,y)$ is a basis of $F^2$ then you can easily prove that $\left(xx^T, xy^T, yx^T, yy^T\right)$ is a basis of $V$. In this basis the matrix of $T(A)$ is : \begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \mu & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \mu\end{bmatrix}\end{align} So $\det(T(A)) = \lambda^2 \mu^2 = \det(A)^2$.

This will hold also for every matrix $A$ since every matrix is a limit of diagonalisable matrices.

This method also can be easily generalized to the $n\times n$ case :

$$\det (T(A)) = \det(A)^n$$

Comment: "Every matrix is a limit of diagonalizable matricies".... really?  I've never heard of this before.

Comment: Yes. But the diagonalization has to be in the algebraic closure of $F$. And for a proof of that you can see : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459522/density-of-diagonalizable-matrices

Comment: This answer is problematic e.g. for the field $\mathbb F_p$.  Algebraic closure uses a lot of machinery and explaining what you mean by limits over a field with positive characteristic is also an issue.